# Key.toUrlSafe() - how to get entity by urlSafeKey?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

> com.google.cloud.datastore.Key

has a `toUrlSafe` method()

how do I recreate the key from this url safe string? Key has only methods like `getParent`, `getId`, `getName`...

I tried with

> com.google.cloud.datastore.Datastore

key factory, but I haven't found any methods that create key from url safe string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using Java.  In Java, the Key class has a static method fromUrlSafe (https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-clients/latest/com/google/cloud/datastore/Key.html#fromUrlSafe-java.lang.String-).

Comment: omg.. its static.. I always tried to invoke it on instance of Key. I don't know how I overlooked this. Should have checked the source code. Thank you...